# MySQL update query to prepend digit to existing column with integers values

Tags: mysql, sql, concatenation

I have a mysql database column named like `telephoneNo`

```
Telephone No 
25645656
45454545
45565656
```

I want to prepend two digits XX to every value of `telephoneNo` column

```
Telephone No 
xx25645656
xx45454545
xx45565656
```

I was trying to workout with concat but its not with integer values in my case please help with update query

Comment: Why are these intetgers? Are you planning to subtract one telephone number from another?

Comment: no i just want to insert 92 in front of all numbers in a coloum. this is my requirement

Comment: Telephone numbers are strings. Store them as strings.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`CAST()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/cast-functions.html#function_cast) to convert your integers explicitely:

```
UPDATE t SET phone=CAST(CONCAT('10', phone) AS UNSIGNED)
```

That will work with integer prefixes. However, I don't see solid reason to store phone numbers as integers and not strings

Answer (score 1):

That's a hack change your col to varchar or something.

```
UPDATE table SET telephoneNo=9200000000+telephoneNo;
```

**EDIT**:

This method requires that all your numbers are of the same length, and 8 digits long, if all your numbers are more or less than 8 digits modify the number of 0's after the 92 accordingly

Comment: While this looks good (from operation cost viewpoint) - it requires that all numbers are same length (and also length should be known before `UPDATE`) - so I think that should be mentioned

Comment: I supposed he knows all the lengths and they are all the same as the column is int, and he wants to add 92 to all of the so they are all in the same country or region

Comment: Well, even in same country there could be different numeration length (if we're speaking about phone numbers)

Answer (score 0):

If your `telephone` column is int, you can use `concat` string function to concat with `int` or `string` even like below

```
SELECT CONCAT(xx, telephone);
```

(OR)

```
SELECT CONCAT('xx', telephone);
```

(OR)

Explicitly cast your int column value

```
SELECT CONCAT('xx', CAST(telephone AS CHAR));
```

Comment: You can't rely on implicit conversions in common case (because strict mode could prohibit that)